# Index Match function VBA

Tags: vba, indexing, match

I am trying to make index/match work on my VBA programme without any success.
I am trying to Match column A from "comparison" with column "A" from previous extract and return column K. All of this while looping through each row. I've already tested everything and it works fine. The only issue now is to make this Index/Match work.

```
Sub Delta_Analysis()

Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Dim sheet_refresh_instructions As Excel.Worksheet
Set sheet_refresh_instructions = wb.Worksheets("Refresh instructions")

Dim sheet_previous_extract As Excel.Worksheet
Set sheet_previous_extract = wb.Worksheets("Previous extract")

Dim sheet_current_extract As Excel.Worksheet
Set sheet_current_extract = wb.Worksheets("Current extract")

Dim sheet_comparison As Excel.Worksheet
Set sheet_comparison = wb.Worksheets("Comparison")

Dim sheet_historical_changes As Excel.Worksheet
Set sheet_historical_changes = wb.Worksheets("Historical changes")

'Start manipulating objects

sheet_previous_extract.UsedRange.ClearContents
sheet_current_extract.UsedRange.Copy
sheet_previous_extract.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
sheet_current_extract.UsedRange.ClearContents

sheet_refresh_instructions.Activate
Range("C6").Select

    Selection.Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True
    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "http://jira3.ms.com/jira/sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-excel-current-fields/53756/SearchRequest-53756.xls?tempMax=1000"
    ActiveWindow.Visible = False
    Windows("SearchRequest-53756.xls").Visible = False

Dim wb1 As Excel.Workbook
Set wb1 = Excel.Workbooks("SearchRequest-53756.xls")
Dim sheet_Jira As Excel.Worksheet
Set sheet_Jira = wb1.Worksheets("general_report")

sheet_Jira.Activate
sheet_Jira.Range("1:3").EntireRow.Delete
sheet_Jira.UsedRange.Copy

sheet_current_extract.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

wb1.Close

With sheet_comparison
    .Range("A2:K" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).ClearContents
End With

sheet_current_extract.Range("a2", sheet_current_extract.Range("a2").End(xlDown)).Copy
    Sheets("Comparison").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

Dim i As Integer
i = 2

Do While sheet_previous_extract.Cells(i, 1) <> ""

Cells(i, 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(sheet_previous_extract.Range("K:K"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(sheet_comparison.Range("A:A"), sheet_previous_extract.Range("A:A"), 0))

i = i + 1

Loop


End Sub
```

Comment: You are trying to match a column value `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(sheet_comparison.Range("A:A"), `  this needs to be a single value.

Comment: also, look at maybe adding the proper sheetname like `'SheetName'!$A$1`

Comment: Hi, I've tried to change to  Sheets("Comparison").Cells(i,2) ... still not working @Nathan_Sav

Comment: What you are doing is incorrect, from `worksheetfunction.index` you'll get a value, you can't say `a:a` as this will be the whole column, to do that way you need to use `.formula` and put the formula in, you need your first argument to be a value, so 1st time match `1st value` 2nd time `2nd value`  so looking at your code `sheet_comparison.Range("A:A"), ` needs to be something like `match(Cells(i, 1)....`

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Thanks for the advices. I made it work. However, now each time VBA can't find the value of the index match, it stops looping and return an error message. Any clue how to bypass that ? (I already  tried application.match... , IsError ...) Thanks again for the previous answer !

Comment: You could try a countif before hand, then if >0 do the match, or read the MSDN help on the function and see what it returns in error, it could be `nothing` as an empty object, or an error code for you to trap.